# Grails criteria or HQL for MySQL query with left join and date functions

Tags: mysql, grails, hql

I have a MySQL database where sales of certain items are stored. I would like to compare the sales of two subsequent days in the past, e.g. 10 days in the past and 9 days in the past. I worked out the MySQL query to do so:

```
select s1.sales - s2.sales from ProductSales as s1
left join ProductSales as s2 on s2.date >= DATE(DATE_ADD(Now(), INTERVAL '-10' DAY)) and s2.date <= DATE(DATE_ADD(Now(), INTERVAL '-9' DAY)) and s2.product_id = s1.product_id
where s1.date >= DATE(DATE_ADD(Now(), INTERVAL '-9' DAY));
```

I want to do this programmatically in a Grails application and I need to transform this query into a criterion or HQL query. How would I do this?

**Update**: I tried like this:

```
def date1 = new Date() - 2
def date2 = new Date() - 1
def sales = ProductSales.executeQuery( """
    select s1.sales - s2.sales from ProductSales s1
    left join ProductSales s2
    where s1.date >= :date2
    and s2.date >= :date1 and s2.date < :date2 and s2.product_id = s1.product_id""",
[ date1: date1, date2: date2 ] )
```

Unfortunately, this gives me:

```
ERROR hql.ast.ErrorCounter -  Path expected for join!
ERROR hql.ast.ErrorCounter -  Invalid path: 's2.sales'
ERROR hql.ast.ErrorCounter -  right-hand operand of a binary operator was null
ERROR hql.ast.ErrorCounter -  Invalid path: 's2.date'
ERROR hql.ast.ErrorCounter - <AST>:0:0: unexpected end of subtree
ERROR hql.ast.ErrorCounter -  left-hand operand of a binary operator was null
ERROR hql.ast.ErrorCounter -  Invalid path: 's2.date'
ERROR hql.ast.ErrorCounter - <AST>:0:0: unexpected end of subtree
ERROR hql.ast.ErrorCounter -  left-hand operand of a binary operator was null
ERROR hql.ast.ErrorCounter -  Invalid path: 's2.product_id'
ERROR hql.ast.ErrorCounter - <AST>:0:0: unexpected end of subtree
ERROR hql.ast.ErrorCounter -  left-hand operand of a binary operator was null
ERROR logging.impl.SLF4JLog - QuerySyntaxException occurred when processing request: [GET] /app/dashboard
Path expected for join!
```

**Update 2**: As I cannot answer my own question, I add my response here:

Apparently this works as it should:

```
def now = new Date()
def date1 = now - 2
def date2 = now - 1
def sales = ProductSales.executeQuery( """
    select s1.owner, s1.sales - s2.sales from ProductSales s1, ProductSales s2
    where s1.date >= :date2 and s1.date < :now 
    and s2.date >= :date1 and s2.date < :date2 and s2.product = s1.product""",
    [ date1: date1, date2: date2, now: now ]
    )
```

I'm not entirely sure what's the difference between a `left join` and a `select from T1, T2`, though. Appart from that, I added an upper bound (`now`) for the more recent entry and changed the `product_id` to `product`.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this works as it should:

```
def now = new Date()
def date1 = now - 2
def date2 = now - 1
def sales = ProductSales.executeQuery( """
    select s1.owner, s1.sales - s2.sales from ProductSales s1, ProductSales s2
    where s1.date >= :date2 and s1.date < :now 
    and s2.date >= :date1 and s2.date < :date2 and s2.product = s1.product""",
    [ date1: date1, date2: date2, now: now ]
    )
```

I'm not entirely sure what's the difference between a `left join` and a `select from T1, T2`, though. Appart from that, I added an upper bound (`now`) for the more recent entry and changed the `product_id` to `product`.